# a function defined on $c_{0}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Can somebody help me ,please? I have the following function:
$$\phi:c_{o}\to \mathbb{R}$$, $\phi(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1}(-2)^{1-n}x_{n}$, where $c_{0}$ is the set of the sequences of real numbers convergent to $0$. I was asked to prove that this function is well defined. So I have to show that, for every sequence in $c_{0}$, $(x_{n})$, $\phi(x) \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $x_{n} \in c_{0}$; there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $|x_{n}|<1$, for every $n \ge N$; so, $|\phi(x)|\le 2(\sum_{n=1}^{N}|x_{n}|\frac{1}{2^{n}}+\sum_{n> N}\frac {1}{2^{n}})$; but this sequence $x_{n}$ is bounded, because is convergent; so $|\phi(x)|\le M \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{2^{n}}$; and calculating this sum, it gives a real number; is this correct?

Comment: What you have written is not true: "there exists $N \in \mathbb{N} : x_n =0  \ \ \forall n \geq N $" :

What you can say is this:  "there exists $N \in \mathbb{N} : |x_n| < 1  \(for\ example) \ \ \forall n \geq N $"

Comment: There exists a $N$, such that $|x_{n}|<1$, for every $n \ge N$;

Comment: Thats my point, I am sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Or, instead of $1$, we can take any number positive..

Comment: But then what you have is this:

$| \phi(x) |= 2 | [\ +\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{(-2)^{n}}x_{n} + \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(-2)^{n}}x_{n} \   ]  |$

Comment: I applied the module ineguality and I obtained what I wrote in the problem.. I corrected it.

Comment: It is not necessary to say that the sequence is bounded, because you have finite terms in your first summation. What yo do have to say is that $\sum_{n> N}\frac {1}{2^{n}}$ is finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ | \phi(x) |< 2 ( \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{2^{n}} |x_{n}| + \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}} \ ) = 2 (C + 2 - \frac{1-\frac{1}{2^{N}}}{1-\frac{1}{2}})\in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \phi (x) \in \mathbb{R} $

Comment: Who is $C$? I dont understand how you obtained that result..can you detail a bit?Thank you!

Comment: Probably $C$ is your notation for that sum..but I dont agree with something...wasnt suppose to be $ \frac{1-\frac{1}{2^{N}}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: $C:= \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{2^{n}} |x_{n}|$ and you are right about the 2nd observation; I was distracted, sorry!

Comment: ok,thanks!..no problrm